# RSA расшифровка

Tags: python, rsa, decrypt

Пытаюсь сделать алгоритм RSA
Открытый и закрытый ключ я нашел.
Пытаюсь зашифровать и дешифровать сообщение.

**ИДЕЯ**: перевести символы в ASCII

```
def perevod_v_ASCII(M:str):
    ASCII_znach_message=[]
    for i in M:
        ASCII_znach_message.append(ord(i))
        
    return ASCII_znach_message

def encrypt(M_ascii:list, e, N):
    C=[]
    for i in M_ascii:
        C.append(round(pow(i,e)%N))
    return C
def decrypt(C:list, d, N):
    M=[]
    for i in C:
        M.append(chr(round(pow(i,d)%N)))
    return M
```

Что можно сделать?

[image: Консоль]

Comment: def decrypt(C:list, d, N):
    for i in C:
         yield chr(round(pow(i, d, N)))

Comment: yield поможет))